# Why does this pipe work?

Tags: c, unix, process, pipe

I am trying to understand pipes. The program works fine (the parent sends the message "hello" to its child and the child prints it. I do not understand two things:

- wouldn't the program halt at some point because let's say the child closes the write descriptor and in the same time, the parent would also close the write descriptor?
- why isn't it required to open the descriptors after closing them?

---

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){

    int desc[2];
    pipe(desc);

    int pid = fork();

    if(pid == 0){
        while(1){
            char buffer[100];
            close(desc[1]);
            read(desc[0], buffer, 100);
            printf("Child: recieved message - '%s'\n", buffer);
        }
    }
    if(pid > 0){
        while(1){
            sleep(1);
            char buffer[100];
            strcpy(buffer, "Hello, child!");
            close(desc[0]);
            write(desc[1], buffer, 100);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So little code, so many minor issues:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){

    int desc[2];
    pipe(desc);
```

There's no error check on the `pipe()` call, or the other system calls.  I won't comment further on most of the possibilities.

```
    int pid = fork();
```

The code actually handles a failed `fork()`.

```
    if(pid == 0){
        while(1){
            char buffer[100];
            close(desc[1]);
```

This `close()` should not be inside the `while` loop.  It fails after the first iteration anyway, so no huge damage done, but you should not be repeatedly attempting to close that which is already closed.  It should be moved outside the loop.

```
            read(desc[0], buffer, 100);
```

You don't know how much data was read.  You should pay attention to the results of operations that read data.  If you don't, you're apt to process garbage.  Also, the child gets a return value of zero when the parent dies; there is nothing else to cause the child to die.  Your code should test for when it is time to exit the loop.

```
            printf("Child: received message - '%s'\n", buffer);
```

This assumes that the data read from the pipe was null terminated.  That isn't always guaranteed, but see later for this program.

```
        }
    }
    if(pid > 0){
        while(1){
            sleep(1);
            char buffer[100];
            strcpy(buffer, "Hello, child!");
            close(desc[0]);
```

Another misplaced `close()`; it should also be outside the loop.

```
            write(desc[1], buffer, 100);
```

You initialized 14 bytes of the 100 you write, including a null byte as the last of those bytes.  That's fortunate; it saves the child from having undefined behaviour.  Strictly, the parent has undefined behaviour instead; in practice, it won't be a problem.  Arguably, you should test that the `write()` worked.  If the child dies, the parent gets a `SIGPIPE` and all is well — the parent stops too.

```
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

There's nothing to stop the processes from repeating indefinitely.  You have to interrupt them to stop them.  That's not a good strategy long-term.

You ask:

> - Wouldn't the program halt at some point because let's say the child closes the write descriptor and in the same time, the parent would also close the write descriptor?

The parent can only close its copy of the write descriptor, though it doesn't do that except when it exits.  The child can and does close its copy of the write descriptor on the first pass through the loop (and fails when it tries to do so on subsequent loops — it'll return `EBADF` in `errno` indicating a bad file descriptor.  Similarly with the read descriptors; the parent closes its read descriptor on the first loop and ends up failing on each subsequent iteration.  The child doesn't close its read descriptor until it exits.  There's no interference between the processes.  Immediately after the `fork()`, before either process does anything more, there's a single common open file description with two open file descriptors (wonderful jargon, isn't it!) for each direction.  The `close()` calls affect the file descriptors; the file description is eliminated when there are no file descriptors left referring to it.

> - Why isn't it required to open the descriptors after closing them?

There's no way to reopen closed pipe file descriptors.  And each process only closes the end of the pipe that it isn't using (which is good practice — important, even, as a process won't get EOF if it tries to read from a pipe where it has the write end of the pipe still open).

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps some info about fork() is in place. Upon successful execution, fork creates two [almost identical](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html) processes. The only difference in your case, is the return value of the fork (the parent receives the pid of the child, and the child gets 0). So, the pipes are opened in both processes, and the file descriptors are valid for both. The key here is that what these descriptors represent have been **copied** to both processes.

So, when the child closes the fd, all it is doing is destroying its own file descriptor, not that of its parent.

Note that however, the close of the fd should happen outside the loop. While it is not certain (and in your case, perhaps it did not happen), closing the same file multiple times may cause your program to crash.